# Wordpress, ACF - get_field_object() doesn't work inside columns when custom filter applied

Tags: wordpress, filter, advanced-custom-fields, customcolumn, acfpro

I’m trying to get a fields value and label inside a row in a custom column. Everything works fine when no filters are applied, but when I apply the filter nothing is showing up and I don’t know why.
I've tried using field name and field key, `$post_id` and `$post->ID`, without results.

[image: Filter]

Also, the strange thing is that `get_field()` returns value fine, but I need label as well so I need `get_field_object()`.

Here is the code sample (a bit modified):

```
add_filter('manage_cptName_posts_columns' , 'add_cptName_columns', 1);
function add_cptName_columns($columns) {

    unset( $columns['date'] );

    return array_merge($columns,
        [ 'colum_one'   => 'Column One' ],
        [ 'column_two'      => 'Column Two'] ,
        [ 'date'        => 'Datum unosa' ]
        );
}

add_action('manage_cptName_posts_custom_column' , 'cptName_custom_columns', 10, 2 );
function cptName_custom_columns( $column, $post_id ) {

    // global $post; // tried both $post_id and $post->ID
    switch ( $column ):

        case 'column_one': 
            echo '<pre>' . print_r( get_field_object('field_one', $post_id) , true) . '</pre>';
            break;

        case 'column_two':
            echo '<pre>' . print_r( get_field_object('field_5b0be1c83f5b4') , true) . '</pre>';
            break;

    endswitch;
}
```

Comment: did you try to `var_dump($post_id)` To see if you are getting anything?

Comment: Yes, it is showing up correctly. I don't know why this is happening. I wasted hours figuring this out without results.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution?